# Mock stripe with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, stripe-payments

I'd like to mock the node Stripe SDK in Jest because I don't want to run the mock API server from Stripe but I can't figure how how to do it. I'm creating a `__mocks__` directory and adding `stripe.js` but I can't get anything usable to export.

I typically get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` when calling `strypegw.charges.create()`. I'm using ES6 module syntax so I `import stripe from 'stripe'`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying?

Comment: you will have to mock the `resources` in Stripe-Node as well. Either manually add all the resources in stripe.js or mock them according to 
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/stripe.js#L342

Comment: You could use a service [like this](https://www.testingpays.com) where you can make HTTP calls from your tests easily. Might be simpler than the mocks.

Comment: This is a great question actually, b/c it's not straightforward on mocking Stripe in a "best practice way" if you're using the node dependency. I'll add an answer to solve this below.

Answer (score 16):

```
// your-code.js
const stripe = require('stripe')('key');
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    ...
});

// __mocks__/stripe.js
class Stripe {}
const stripe = jest.fn(() => new Stripe());

module.exports = stripe;
module.exports.Stripe = Stripe;

// stripe.tests.js
const { Stripe } = require('stripe');
const createCustomerMock = jest.fn(() => ({
    id: 1,
    ...
}));
Stripe.prototype.customers = {
    create: createCustomerMock,
};
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey .After exploring a lot this solution works for me .I was trying to mock the stripe module but no luck .This is working fine for me .

Comment: to those who try this with no luck, ensure that as per the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks), the `__mocks__` directory is adjacent to your file

Comment: How should I modify the mock if I wanted to use some nested methods, like stripe.checkout.sessions.create?

Comment: @AleisterCrowley
I think something like 
`Stripe.prototype.checkout = {
    sessions: {
        create: createSessionMock,
    }
};`

Comment: This doesnt stop the Stripe library from making an API call. So you still get "You did not provide an API key" errors

Answer (score 4):

As of `stripe@9.6.0`, you can add a direct `spyOn` to the `Customer` class instead of overriding the entire Stripe class.

**Short answer:**

```js
jest.mock('stripe', () => {
  const stripe = jest.requireActual('stripe');
  jest.spyOn(stripe.resources.Customers.prototype, 'create')
    .mockImplementation(() => (
      Promise.resolve({id: 'stripe-test-id'})
    ));
  return stripe;
})
```

---

**Long answer:**

1. You don't want to override the main `Stripe` class because there are a lot of static values and utility helpers your application might use such as `Stripe.errors.StripeError`. It would be superfluous to mock things that don't need mocking.
2. The reason why `Stripe.prototype.customer` doesn't work because `.customer` is not a method until *after instantiation*. See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/stripe.js#L124
3. Luckily Stripe exposes their resources statically via `Stripe.resources`. So you can spy on the resources directly.  When the real Stripe gets instantiated, it'll reference the spies instead of the real class for the particular resource you're trying to mock. See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/stripe.js#L51
4. A quick and dirty way to mock an entire resource is to override the resource references like this: `Stripe.resources.Customers = {create: jest.fn()};`. I would not recommend it for reasons stated in point 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution :

```
jest.mock("stripe", () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(function {
    return {
      charges: {
        create: () => "fake stripe response",
      },
    };
  });
});
```

I found it in jest documentation about [ES6 Class Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter)

Comment: This actually didn't work when I tested it. I kept getting an error when calling the constructor like so `const stripe = new Stripe();`. The other answer from @Sergey seemed to work. Any reason why that would be the case?

Comment: yeah same with me -- sergey's worked. would love an answer to this

Answer (score 0):

Add this in a helper function and invoke it in jest setup file or at the top of the test when required.

```
// Mocking Stripe object
  const elementMock = {
    mount: jest.fn(),
    destroy: jest.fn(),
    on: jest.fn(),
    update: jest.fn(),
  };

  const elementsMock = {
    create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(elementMock),
  };

  const stripeMock = {
    elements: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(elementsMock),
    createToken: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    createSource: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  };

  // Set the global Stripe
  window.Stripe = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(stripeMock);
```

With this approach, you can easily test your stripe related code as well

```
// Ex. of a token successfully created mock
  stripeMock.createToken.mockResolvedValue({
    token: {
      id: 'test_id',
    },
  });

  // Ex. of a failure mock
  stripeMock.createToken.mockResolvedValue({
    error: {
      code: 'incomplete_number',
      message: 'Your card number is incomplete.',
      type: 'validation_error',
    },
  });
```